# How should I read/interpret this notation?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, notation, vector-space-isomorphism

The notation used is $\boldsymbol{v} \mapsto [\boldsymbol{v}]_B$, I've read it before but I don't really understand. It appears in the following proof for context:

> Two finite-dimensional vector spaces $V$ and $W$ with the same dimension are isomorphic.
>
> **Proof:** Assume $\dim V=\dim W=n$. Let $\boldsymbol{b_1},\ldots,\boldsymbol {b_n}$ be a base for $V$. Then $\boldsymbol{v} \mapsto[\boldsymbol{v}]_B$ is an isomorphism between $V$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$, etc...

My guess is it's the mapping of the vector $\boldsymbol{v}$ as a linear combination of the basis vectors in $\boldsymbol{B}$?

Comment: That is quite sloppy. The $\rightarrow$ should be $\mapsto$, and we can only guess that  $B$ stands for $\mathbf b_1,\ldots, \mathbf b_n$. Finally, $[\mathbf v]_B$ is indeed likely the vector of coefficients when $ \mathbf v$ is expressed in terms of $B$

Comment: Yes, I missed the difference in the arrow notation! However, B is not explicitly defined but I assume that's what the author meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector $v$ lies in the vector space $V$ of dimension $n$. Once you put a coordinate system on $V$ (which is to say, once you choose a base $B$), then you can find the coordinates of the vector $v$. This is what they mean with $[v]_B$. So we have

- $v$: A vector in the vector space $V$
- $[v]_B$: The coordinates of the vector $v$ using the base $B$, which is to say the tuple $(v_1, v_2, \ldots,v_n)$ of numbers such that $$v = v_1b_1+v_2b_2 + \cdots v_nb_n$$

Using the base $B$ it is not difficult to translate between these two. That's what $v\mapsto [v]_B$ means.

Comment: So essentially $\boldsymbol{v}$ is any vector in the vector space V, and since we can create endless of different bases $A, B, C$, etc. if we choose to write v using the base $B$ we get $[\boldsymbol{v}]_B$ and using the base A we get $[\boldsymbol{v}]_A$, etc.?

Comment: @edwindakwesi Yes, essentially.

Answer (score 2):

Although I do not know this notation it is clear from the context that $ v\to[ v]_B$ denotes the coordinate isomorphism, so if $B=(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ is a basis of $V$, then $v$ has a unique linear combination $v=a_1b_1+\ldots+a_nb_n$, where $a_i$ are scalars from your base field $K$ ($\mathbb R$ in your case). Now $[v]_B = (a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in K^n$.

Easier to define is the inverse:
$$ K^n\ni (a_1,\ldots,a_n) \to a_1b_1+\ldots+a_nb_n\in V$$